# Entry form and visualize with PySimpleGUI in 2 different sheets

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, pysimplegui

I'm trying to export in an existing file a row of datas in sheet1 every time a person complete the form but I also have a button to visualize some cells in sheet2. Every time I try to entry information the file got corrupted and tries to save the most data and no info is exported. Maybe I need to active 2 sheets at different times?

```
EXCEL_FILE = 'example.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
workbook = load_workbook(filename='example.xlsx')
workbook.sheetnames
workbook.active = workbook['sheet2']
sheet = workbook.active

layout = [
        [sg.Text('Por favor rellenar los siguientes campos:')],
        [sg.Text('Fecha de Inicio', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Fecha de Inicio')],
        [sg.Text('Hora de Inicio', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Hora de Inicio')]]

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None



while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Salir':
        break
    if event == 'Limpiar':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Confirmar':
        wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel('example.xlsx', index=False)
        wb.save('example.xlsx')
        sg.popup('Informe enviado!')
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Visualizar':
        for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1,
                                    max_row=20,
                                     min_col=1,
                                     max_col=3,
                                     values_only=True):
            sg.Print(value)
window.close()
```

Comment: do you get error message when you run code? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `df.to_excel()` and `wb.save()` - you write two different data. And I don't understand why you use `read_excel()` and `load_workbook() - you read the same file with two different modules, later you write it also with two different methods. You should use onlye one module.

Comment: @furas When I run the code there isn't a message error, only the message appears from excel when I open the file. Also I'm trying everything to get the output, so I have 2 modules, my bad.